# Estoy tratando de resolverlo, alguien que me asesore gracias

Tags: javascript

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

*El ingrediente de cierta comida está en mal estado. Hay que sacar los ingredientes próximos a éste, ya que deben estar contaminados también. La función recibe un objeto `menu` que contiene las comidas del día. "comida" es un array de ingredientes. Si `ingrediente` está en el array, devolver un array con el ingrediente y los elementos en un índice de diferencia.*

*Ejemplo:*

```js
let menuDelDia = {
  raviolesConSalsa: ["Harina", "Sal", "-Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
  bagnaCauda: ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"],
  tallarines: ["Harina", "Pollo", "Aceite", "Huevos", "Tomates", "Cebolla"]
}

ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Peceto") // devuelve => ["Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"];

ingredienteEnMalEstado(menuDelDia, "tallarines", "Aceite") // devuelve => ["Pollo", "Aceite", "Huevos"];
```

*En caso de no encontrarse el ingrediente en la comida, devolver `El menú está perfecto`.*

*NOTA: No utilizar el método "includes".*

*Tu código: Añado array vacío que contiene ingredientes en mal estado:*

```js
function ingredienteEnMalEstado(menu, comida, ingrediente) {
  ingrediente1 = [];

  //Creo un for para encontrar los ingredientes y sus ingredientes próximos que también están contaminados.
  for (var i = 0; i < comida.length; i++) {

    // Si ingrediente se encuentra en el primer elemento de comida entonces el .push lo hago sobre comida[0] y comida[1] que serían los ingredientes en mal estado.
    if (comida[0] === ingrediente) {
      ingrediente1.push(comida[0], comida[1]);

      //Acá accedería al último y penúltimo elemento del array comida y lo agrego a la lista de elementos en mal estado.
    } else if (comida[comida.length - 1] === ingrediente) {
      ingrediente1.push(comida[comida.length - 1],
        comida[comida.length - 2]);

      // En caso que Ingrediente se encuentre en medio del array, agrego el ingrediente y los elementos próximos a este.
    } else if (comida[i] === ingrediente) {
      ingrediente1.push(comida[i], comida[i - 1], comida[i + 1]);
    } else if (comida[i] !== ingrediente) {

      //en caso que no esté ingrediente retorno el siguiente mensaje.
      return 'El menú está perfecto'
    }
  }
  return ingrediente1;
};
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?... también coloca un título relevante.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let menuDelDia = {
   "raviolesConSalsa": ["Harina", "Sal", "-Huevos", "Aceite", "Peceto", "Ricota"],
   "bagnaCauda": ["Ajo", "Anchoas", "Aceite", "Crema", "Papas", "Zanahorias"],
   "tallarines": ["Harina", "Pollo", "Aceite", "Huevos", "Tomates", "Cebolla"]
}

function ingredienteEnMalEstado( menu, laComida, ingrediente ) {
    let ingrediente1 = [];

      // inicializamos el array que contiene los ingredientes de cada comida, para que 
      // el código quede más limpio, aunque podríamos usar menu[ comida ][ i ]
    let comida = menu[ laComida ];

      // igual con el largo del array
    let largo = comida.length;
    for( var i = 0; i < largo; i++ ) {        
        if( comida[ 0 ] === ingrediente ) {
            ingrediente1.push( comida[ 0 ], comida[ 1 ] );
            return ingrediente1;
        }
        else if( comida[ largo -1 ] === ingrediente ) {
            ingrediente1.push( comida[ largo -1 ], comida[ largo -2 ] );
            return ingrediente1;
        }
        else if( comida[ i ] === ingrediente ) {
            ingrediente1.push( comida[ i ], comida[ i -1 ], comida[ i +1 ] );
            return ingrediente1;
        }
    }
    return 'El menú está perfecto'
}

console.log( ingredienteEnMalEstado( menuDelDia, "raviolesConSalsa", "Peceto" ));

console.log( ingredienteEnMalEstado( menuDelDia, "tallarines", "Aceite" ));
```

Básicamente, los errores en tu código son dos:

a) usas **comida.length** que te devuelve el largo de el nombre de la comida en cuestión, cuando deberías usar **menu[ comida ].length**.

b) para obtener los ingredientes usas **comida[ i ]**, que te devuelve una letra del nombre de la comida, cuando deberías usar **menu[ comida ][ i ]**.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. No sabemos con exactitud cuál es el problema del OP, o bueno, al menos no lo especifica, por lo cual sería mejor esperar a que el OP mejore su pregunta.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev, hola maestro, el problema es que por un lado usa **comida.length** lo que le devuelve el largo del nombre de la comida, y después intenta un **push( comida[ i ] );** que guarda una letra del nombre. debiendo usar **menu[ comida ][ i ]**.